# How to apply stat_sum to a particular grouping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code that produces the following graph.

```
colvec <-c("white", "white","gray85", "gray85", "gray58", "gray58", "gray33", "gray33","black", "black") 

ggplot(nut, aes(Date, Nitrate, group=Wetland, shape=Hydrology)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=Wetland), colour="black", size=4)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colvec) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22))+
  facet_grid(. ~ Hydrology) +
  ylab ("Nitrate (mg/L) ") +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='white'), 
        panel.grid = element_line(color = NA),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = NA),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(size=10, colour="black"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=0.1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=0.3))
```

[image]

I can't figure out how to use `stat_sum` in such a way that the 5 points over each date are averaged together.  The program treats each differently shaded point (corresponding to Wetland) as its own mean.  I want to preserve the grouping by Wetland and show this as different shades, but also show a mean for all the y values over each date.

Data

```
     Date  Wetland Hydrology  Nitrate 
1  17-Jun     One    Pulsed 0.2647287              
2  18-Jul     One    Pulsed 0.1807388             
3   1-Aug     One    Pulsed 0.9895910      
4  15-Aug     One    Pulsed 0.6566667       
5   7-Nov     One    Pulsed 0.2150000      
6  17-Jun     Two    Static 0.2134027      
7  18-Jul     Two    Static 0.1971669      
8   1-Aug     Two    Static 0.4774424       
9  15-Aug     Two    Static 0.3110000      
10  7-Nov     Two    Static 0.3333333       
11 17-Jun   Three    Pulsed 0.3369253       
12 18-Jul   Three    Pulsed 0.2056284       
13  1-Aug   Three    Pulsed 0.6731924       
14 15-Aug   Three    Pulsed 0.5516667       
15  7-Nov   Three    Pulsed 0.1853333      
16 17-Jun    Four    Static 0.3293668      
17 18-Jul    Four    Static 0.4664748       
18  1-Aug    Four    Static 0.4555003       
19 15-Aug    Four    Static 0.3993333       
20  7-Nov    Four    Static 0.1133333       
21 17-Jun    Five    Static 0.3497963     
22 18-Jul    Five    Static 0.3618659      
23  1-Aug    Five    Static 0.3721719     
24 15-Aug    Five    Static 0.2916667      
25  7-Nov    Five    Static 0.2526667      
26 17-Jun     Six    Pulsed 0.2779667       
27 18-Jul     Six    Pulsed 0.7609531      
28  1-Aug     Six    Pulsed 0.7177083       
29 15-Aug     Six    Pulsed 0.6610000       
30  7-Nov     Six    Pulsed 0.2083333       
31 17-Jun   Seven    Pulsed 0.2232040      
32 18-Jul   Seven    Pulsed 0.3655621       
33  1-Aug   Seven    Pulsed 0.7006131       
34 15-Aug   Seven    Pulsed 0.4753333      
35  7-Nov   Seven    Pulsed 0.3206667    
36 17-Jun   Eight    Static 0.3339319       
37 18-Jul   Eight    Static 0.3286641       
38  1-Aug   Eight    Static 0.4390918      
39 15-Aug   Eight    Static 0.3276667       
40  7-Nov   Eight    Static 0.2446667       
41 17-Jun    Nine    Static 0.3456627      
42 18-Jul    Nine    Static 0.2519814      
43  1-Aug    Nine    Static 0.3807550      
44 15-Aug    Nine    Static 0.3873333      
45  7-Nov    Nine    Static 0.1663333       
46 17-Jun     Ten    Pulsed 0.4135023      
47 18-Jul     Ten    Pulsed 0.1921382       
48  1-Aug     Ten    Pulsed 0.3898374       
49 15-Aug     Ten    Pulsed 0.2700000       
50  7-Nov     Ten    Pulsed 0.1216667
```

dput(nut)

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("1-Aug", 
"15-Aug", "17-Jun", "18-Jul", "7-Nov"), class = "factor"), Wetland = structure(c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("Eight", "Five", "Four", "Nine", "One", 
"Seven", "Six", "Ten", "Three", "Two"), class = "factor"), Hydrology = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("Pulsed", "Static"), class = "factor"), Nitrate = c(0.264728748, 
0.180738787, 0.989591021, 0.656666667, 0.215, 0.213402705, 0.197166881, 
0.477442378, 0.311, 0.333333333, 0.33692531, 0.205628403, 0.67319236, 
0.551666667, 0.185333333, 0.329366831, 0.466474791, 0.455500298, 
0.399333333, 0.113333333, 0.349796312, 0.361865927, 0.372171941, 
0.291666667, 0.252666667, 0.277966745, 0.760953065, 0.717708344, 
0.661, 0.208333333, 0.223203974, 0.365562124, 0.700613059, 0.475333333, 
0.320666667, 0.333931889, 0.328664129, 0.439091764, 0.327666667, 
0.244666667, 0.345662714, 0.251981433, 0.380755049, 0.387333333, 
0.166333333, 0.413502261, 0.192138209, 0.389837374, 0.27, 0.121666667
)), .Names = c("Date", "Wetland", "Hydrology", "Nitrate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
```

Comment: You aren't going to get very good answers (or possibly any) unless you give us an example that we can run completely ourselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's kinda hard to answer without your data (because I'd normally test it first!), but I think you could `aggregate` your Nitrate data by Date and Hydrology and calculate the mean, then plot using an additional `geom_point` with the different `data.frame`.

Does this work...

```
nutm <- aggregate( Nitrate ~ Date + Hydrology , data = nut , FUN = mean )

p <-ggplot(nut, aes(Date, Nitrate, shape = Hydrology)) +
  geom_point( data = nut , aes( fill = Wetland , group=Wetland ), colour="black", size=4)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colvec) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22))+
  facet_grid(. ~ Hydrology) +
  ylab ("Nitrate (mg/L) ") +
  geom_point( data = nutm , aes( x = Date , y = Nitrate) , color = "red" , fill = "red" , size = 4 ) +
  theme(legend.position="none",
        panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='white'), 
        panel.grid = element_line(color = NA),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = NA),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(size=10, colour="black"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=0.1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=0.3))

p
```

This gives me your chart with a red average mark for each date...
[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error "Error in geom_point(aes(fill = Wetland), colour = "black", size = 4) +  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator".  I just put the data up.

Comment: Paste the data using `dput( nut ) ` we can then copy and paste the output of that into R.

Comment: @user2055130 OK, does it work now? I had to remove the grouping element from the ggplot call and put it in the geom_point, because it is not shared by the second geom_point layer. Please note that by doing it this way you will not be able to map aesthetics like colour, fill and shape to the second layer, only set them. There is probably a more ggplot way of doing this but this should get you started I hope. Can you please also `dput` the contents of `colvec`?

Comment: Ok, the colvec just needs to be arranged like this `colvec <-c("white", "gray85", "gray58", "gray33",  "black", "white", "gray85", "gray58", "gray33",  "black")` and then the Date factor re-ordered.  Then it's perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: Instead, you could use the function `grey` to make your `colvec` and ensure it is evenly spaced like this... `colvec <- grey( seq( 0 , 1 , length.out = 10 ) ) ` whcih gives `[1] "#000000" "#1C1C1C" "#393939" "#555555" "#717171" "#8E8E8E" "#AAAAAA" "#C6C6C6" "#E3E3E3"
[10] "#FFFFFF"`